# mysqli gives 0 result for query in php but gives correct result in terminal

Tags: php, mysql

I've got two tables and an association table of those two. I'm trying to run a query which gives my desired result running the code from terminal, but gives zero or unknown column result if executed from php.

This is my query:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM projects p 
JOIN projects_groups pg on p.projectid = pg.projectid 
JOIN groups g on g.groupid = pg.groupid 
WHERE p.projectid = 'bestproject'");
```

Running the code exactly like above gives me back 0 result. If i switch 'bestproject' with a variable it gives me back an unkwown column bestproject error.

What's wrong with my query?

UPDATE: I had a stupid error in my function that was recieving the result, which caused my confusion. The receiver function was showing an empty array when the query was successfull, and also the function that handled the query was showing empty or failed result when the query was wrong (Not the one above). I kept searching for the error in the query instead to look at somewhere else. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Can you explain a little more on "above gives me back 0 result". Are you talking about num_rows on result?

Comment: Yes the num_row is 0, but it's not possible. I've made the records manually just to test it, and it works in terminal.

Comment: It may actually be returning correctly. `num_rows` is not exactly foolproof. From the docs: `The behaviour of mysqli_num_rows() depends on whether buffered or unbuffered result sets are being used. For unbuffered result sets, mysqli_num_rows() will not return the correct number of rows until all the rows in the result have been retrieved.`

Comment: Can't find anything wrong in the query. I believe you should try and see if mysql is returning any errors (due to formatting) by putting this query in a variable and querying inside an if statement like in the manual : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: You may need `store_result()` to buffer the result into memory. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php

Answer (score 0):

Everything you have done there is selected what tables and content. You need to have a php function that writes out the content as well.

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

As you can see so does the echo writing out the content of the tables. You also can make so you don't have to use $row['id'] Just save it in a another variable:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      $id = $row['id'];
      $first = $row['firstname'];
      $last = $row['last'];

      echo "id: $id - Name: $first $last<br>";

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Of course you need to have some content in the tables

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do have a function that handles the result, and in fact that caused the error. I passed the result to a function that was using an empty variable instead of the result. It was a stupid mistake, i did not updated it correctly after changing the function that handles the query.

Comment: That you uses a function that handles the result can be a good thing. I would otherwise do a $output = "YOUR CONTENT": And then just do a echo $output; where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem does not make sense to me. The unknown column error is caused because you didn't use the single quotes so MySQL will try to find a column with your variables name instead of handling it as a value.

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM projects p 
JOIN projects_groups pg on p.projectid = pg.projectid 
JOIN groups g on g.groupid = pg.groupid 
WHERE p.projectid = '".$argument."'");
```

To avoid SQL injection it's better to use PDO to pass arguments. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Mysqli offers prepared statements too, you don't *have* to use PDO!

Comment: The argument is generated by the application so I think SQL injection is not possible here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers, you helped me to look somewhere else.

The truth is that i've made a mistake somewhere else. I was loading the result into an array while i only wanted to get one result, and the function that recieved it was actually trying to get data out of a different variable...

It's kinda embarassing, but i've spent hours to figure it out, so i had to ask.

Sorry and thanks for the help!